# Flutter Tests for Responsive Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, responsive-design

I want to test if the widget is present when the screen size changes.

My Sample try:

```
class ResponsiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResponsiveWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: isMobile(context)
            ? const Text("This now has list of icons for Desktop")
            : const Icon(Icons.menu),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < maxMobileScreenWidth;
```

Test Case

```
double maxMobileScreenWidth = 799;
  testWidgets('Menu Icon invisible in non-mobile screen test',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    tester.view.physicalSize = Size(maxMobileScreenWidth + 20, 800);
    await tester.pumpWidget(const ResponsiveWidget());

    var menuIcon = find.byIcon(Icons.menu);
    expect(menuIcon, findsNothing);
  });
```

It throws me exception saying:

```
Expected: no matching nodes in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetIconFinder:<exactly one widget with icon "IconData(U+0E3DC)" (ignoring offstage
widgets): Icon(IconData(U+0E3DC), dependencies: [Directionality, IconTheme])>
   Which: means one was found but none were expected
```

How can it see something which it shouldn't have seen. Can someone help me as what i am missing.

It is clear that everything is rendered, is there any way I can stop the rendering of the widgets in a particular range of widget, something similar to mocking may be ?